# How to deactivate text suggestions in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime

Is it possible to deactivate text suggestions for selected TextBoxes in a Windows Store app when no keyboard is attached to the Windows tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TextBox.IsTextPredictionEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.istextpredictionenabled) does the trick. It's true by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could try various [`InputScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.inputscope.aspx) options to see if that helps...

Comment: I tried that already. There seems to be no InputScope which shows the default onscreen keyboard without the text suggestions.

Comment: Maybe changing the `Language` property value would make it go away? Anyways - why would you not want to see the suggestions?